# How to collapse/expand data between rows in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a requirement like, I have to display data first like this, for each row expand/collapse button should be dispalyed.

Job data

```
           JobId    JobName   Descriptipn   Type
         -------------------------------------------
(+)(-)     1          A         ABC          Type1
(+)(-)     2          B         ABC          Type2
```

If I clicked on expand button, then a ajax method will be called and loads job and its related data from DB.  Now the selected job data should be displayed in job1 area, that means,
job1 row should be expanded , job2,job3....jobn should be same as earlier.

If I clicked on job2 then, job1 should be collapsed and job2 should be expanded.

I am able to display above one with table, but I am unable to achieve this expand/collapse functionality.

Data of selected job is large data, it has around 3,4 tables. How to display such large data?

While I am googling found that its not recommended to use div tag inside tr tag.

Here comes my code

```
   <table class="data">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th onclick="javascript:void(0);"><bean:message key="jsp.sp.jobs.jobData.jobNumber"/></th>
                <th onclick="javascript:void(0);"><bean:message key="jsp.sp.jobs.jobData.jobName"/></th>
                <th onclick="javascript:void(0);"><bean:message key="jsp.sp.jobs.jobData.jobDescription"/></th>
                <th onclick="javascript:void(0);"><bean:message key="jsp.sp.jobs.jobData.jobType"/></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <% int i = 1; %>
        <tbody>
            <logic:iterate id="job" name="jobListe" type="com.abc.model.sp.job.JobVO">

                <bean:define id="pk" name="job" property="primaryKey"/>
                <bean:define id="rowClass">
                    <%=job.equals(serviceProtokollDRS.getSelectedJob()) ? 
                            "mark" : Globalerie.EVEN_OR_ODD[i]%>
                </bean:define>

                <tr class="<bean:write name="rowClass"/>" id="<bean:write name="pk"/>"
                    onclick="javascript:Job.select('<bean:write name="pk"/>');">
                    <td><bean:write name="job" property="jobNummer"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="job" property="jobName"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="job" property="desc"/></td>
                    <td><bean:write name="job" property="type"/></td>
                </tr>
                <% i = 1 -i; %>
            </logic:iterate>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

They are not using jquery in this, only javascript.

Comment: Who said you can create tables only with `<table>`? :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a row beneath each row with a div for holding the expanded data (using colspan to fill the width of the table), and then build out the content within that cell. Keep track of the currently expanded cell element, and that'll allow you to easily remove it when expanding another.

This isn't the cleanest solution, but without a library like jQuery you don't have many options.

```js
var expanded = null;

expand = function(target, jobId) {
  // retrieve data for jobId
  if (expanded) {
    expanded.parentNode.removeChild(expanded);  
  }
  
  var dataRow = target.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling,
      dataCol = dataRow.firstElementChild.nextElementSibling;
  
  appendData(dataCol, jobId);
};

collapse = function(target) {
  if (expanded) {
    var dataRow = target.parentNode.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
    if (expanded.parentNode.parentNode === dataRow) {
      expanded.parentNode.removeChild(expanded);
      expanded = null;
    }
  }
};


var appendData = function(cell, jobId) {
    var dataTable = document.createElement('TABLE'),
      tr = document.createElement('TR'),
      td = document.createElement('TD');
  var t = document.createTextNode("Job data for " + jobId);
  td.appendChild(t);
  tr.appendChild(td);
  dataTable.appendChild(tr);
  cell.appendChild(dataTable);
  
  expanded = dataTable;
}
```

```css
th, td {
  padding: 5px;
}

.actionCol a {
  text-decoration: initial;
}

td table {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class="header">
    <th class="actionCol">
      <!-- empty for header -->
    </th>
    
    <th class="colHeader">
      Job ID
    </th>
    <th class="colHeader">
      Job Name
    </th>
    <th class="colHeader">
      Job Description
    </th>
  </thead>
  
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="actionCol">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="expand(this, 'j-1');">+</a> |
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="collapse(this);">-</a>
    </td>
    <td class="colCell">
      j-1
    </td>
    <td class="colCell">
      Job 1
    </td>
    <td class="colCell">
      This is the first job
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data"><td></td><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
  
  <tr class="row">
    <td class="actionCol">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="expand(this, 'j-2');">+</a> |
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="collapse(this);">-</a>
    </td>
    <td class="colCell">
      j-2
    </td>
    <td class="colCell">
      Job 2
    </td>
    <td class="colCell">
      This is the second job
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="data"><td></td><td colspan="3"></td></tr>
</table>
```